# Dynamically adding control in asp.net depends on datatable count

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to ask if it is possible to add a button or checkbox dynamically depending on the count of the datatable. Like I have 10 records in the database. Each value will be displayed in the dynamic button or checkbox.

What I would like to do is to create a list of buttons like LinkedIn when adding skills. There is a suggested skills on the modal and when I click the skill it transfers in a different panel.

Please See SC:
[image: Please See SC]

I hope someone helps me with this. Thank you!

Comment: You can refer this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464373/dynamically-adding-multiple-user-controls-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub b1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b1.Click
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables", con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim MyTableCount As Integer = ds.Tables.Count
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim btn As Button = New Button
            Dim strr As String = row.Item("TABLE_NAME")

            btn.ID = strr.Substring(0, 2) & 1
            btn.Text = strr.Substring(0, 2)
            btn.Height = 20
            btn.Width = 150

            Panel1.Controls.Add(btn)
        Next row
    End If
End Sub
```